# Basic webserver with node.js and express for serving html file and assets

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm making some frontend experiments and I'd like to have a very basic webserver to quickly start a project and serve the files (one index.html file + some css/js/img files). So I'm trying to make something with node.js and express, I played with both already, but I don't want to use a render engine this time since I'll have only a single static file, with this code I get the html file but not the assets (error 404):

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express.createServer();

app.configure(function(){
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Is there a simple way to do it (in one file if possible) or Express requires the use of a view and render engine ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use <del>[a solution like this in node.js](http://codetwizzle.com/articles/web-server-on-the-fly-node-js/)</del> *(link no longer works)*, as I've blogged about before.

The summarise, install connect with `npm install connect`.

Then paste this code into a file called `server.js` in the same folder as your HTML/CSS/JS files.

```
var util = require('util'),
    connect = require('connect'),
    port = 1337;

connect.createServer(connect.static(__dirname)).listen(port);
util.puts('Listening on ' + port + '...');
util.puts('Press Ctrl + C to stop.');
```

Now navigate to that folder in your terminal and run `node server.js`, this will give you a temporary web server at `http://localhost:1337`

Comment: Perfect, thanks :) Never used Connect alone, I didn't know that would be that simple...

Comment: hey,
using this code i get the error
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://SomeExternalUrl. Origin http://localhost:8888 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

when I try to cross site script.

can you please guide me what and where I need to change to allow this cross site script to run?

Comment: @Guy, it's not about code, it's about browsers policy. In common you should use same domain name on web server and rest server, or you may turn off cross-origin policy in browser. In chrome - by install cors extention or run chrome with special flag(please google).

Comment: I think this is old, I'm getting `has no method 'static'`

Comment: Getting `connect.static is not a function`

Comment: Please check my updated answer as of 6/5/2020. Thanks to the original posters, but this is way easier to do now.

Answer (score 70):

I came across this because I have a similar situation. I don't need or like templates. Anything you put in the public/ directory under express gets served as static content (Just like Apache). So I placed my index.html there and used sendfile to handle requests with no file (eg: GET http://mysite/):

```
app.get('/', function(req,res) {
  res.sendfile('public/index.html');
});
```

Comment: And serve the rest of the files with `app.get(/^(.+)$/, function(req, res) { res.sendfile('public/' + req.params[0]); });`

Comment: sometimes one is just looking for something simple for a quick and dirty test...we don't want a super generic and complicated answer... we just want that one-liner that makes you prove/disprove a theory you might have...that is why I found this answer really useful +1

Comment: In express 4.14.3: `express deprecated res.sendfile: Use res.sendFile instead`

Comment: @guzart except if you are building an SPA, index.html is the only one you'll need to server, which is why I was searching for this answer

Comment: @PDN I guess the problem is when inside this index.html you have javascript and css files and other static content that you want to serve.

Answer (score 32):

Following code worked for me.

```
var express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  http = require('http'),
  httpServer = http.Server(app);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/folder_containing_assets_OR_scripts'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
app.listen(3000);
```

this loads page with assets

Comment: Please check my updated answer as of 6/5/2020. Thanks to the original posters, but this is way easier to do now.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to original posters, but their answers are a bit outdated now. It's very, very simple to do. A basic setup looks like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const dir = `${__dirname}/public/`;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(dir + "index.html");
});

app.get("/contact", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(dir + "contact.html");
});

// Serve a 404 page on all other accessed routes, or redirect to specific page
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  //   res.sendFile(dir + "404.html");
  //   res.redirect("/");
});

app.listen(3000);
```

The above example is if you want to serve individual HTML files. If you were serving a single page JS app, this would work.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const dir = `${__dirname}/public/`;

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(dir + "index.html");
});

app.listen(3000);
```

If you need to serve other static assets from within a folder, you can add something like this before you start defining the routes:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Let's say you have a `js` folder inside public like: `public/js`. You could include any of those files inside of your html files using relative paths. For example, let's say `/contact` needs a `contact.js` file. In your `contact.html` file, you can include the script as easy as:

```
<script src="./js/contact.js"></script>
```

Building off of that example, you can do the same with css, images etc.

```
<img src="./images/rofl-waffle.png" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/o-rly-owl.css" />
```

Hope this helps everyone from the future out.

Comment: Change path and file names to suit your apps directory structure of course.