# Path broke in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, nodes

I have a problem from client side with my path for a image or css, my image and css are in the same folder with index.html but index don't see it.

My folder structure:

- index.html
- image.jpeg
- main.css
- server.js

In index.html I ask the path for image and css so:

```
<img src="/image.jpeg">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/main.css">
```

In server.js I ask the path for index so:

```
var app = require('express')();
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Basic webserver with node.js and express for serving html file and assets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443840/basic-webserver-with-node-js-and-express-for-serving-html-file-and-assets)

Comment: Your server gives you index.html just fine, but you've created no routes for the other files it requires.  You need routes for them.  unlike some other web servers, node.js does not serve ANY files by default.  You can use `express.static()` to help you, but you should put those other public files in a separate directory and point `express.static()` at that other public directory so that it won't expose server.js.

Answer (score 0):

Read Express docs before use it: [**serving static files in Express**](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Answer (score -1):

You problem is that you have no way of serving static files.

Include this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

And use the directory 'public' to store your files.

There is a question posted here that is similar to yours and which may provide further clarification. [Basic webserver with node.js and express for serving html file and assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443840/basic-webserver-with-node-js-and-express-for-serving-html-file-and-assets)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13112039)

Comment: Is this more suitable?

Comment: You should be safe now.

Comment: Thanks for the help