# how to arrange client files and node server on the same domain

Tags: node.js, server

I have developed a node.js server and a client app . On my dev machine the server (`app.js` etc) and the client (`index.html` etc) are running from different folders and requests from the client are handled correctly by the server.

Yesterday I uploaded the server files to my remote server (which is shared). The node server app is running OK because it's putting correct entries in a log file. I've also added a simple test to see if the server is running ok :

```
  app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Ridehub server running!');
})
```

and from a browser `https://ridehub2.truro.cc/test` gives the correct response.

The client files are also located on the same site, but now I cannot access `index.html` :

```
Cannot GET /index.html
```

Previously, I was running  a .NET service located in a `bin` folder. With that setup, `index.html` was displayed successfully and the url for accessing the APIs was `\service_name.svc\api_name`.  I have changed `web.config` from the old one (set up for asp.net) for the default web.config for node.js, but I assume I need to do something more to enable the client files to be accessed.

The folder structure on the server is:

```
ridehub2.truro.cc
- index.html
- web.config
- assets // (called by index.html)
- - index-xxx.css
- - index-xxx.js
- service
- - node_modules
- - entry.cjs
- - app.js
- - src
- - package.json
- - - *.js // (as reqd by app.js)
```

Do I need to change this layout, and/or change web.config?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>

    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="service/entry.cjs" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^entry.cjs\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>
         <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>

        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="service/entry.cjs"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

    <!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>-->
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443840). Seems I wasn't asking the correct question.
Nohing to do with web.config, the answer lies in serving the html from node itself:

```
import express from "express";
import http from 'http';
const app = express ();
const httpServer = new http.Server(app);

app.use(express.static('./client'));
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("RideHub server listening on PORT:", port);
  });
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('./index.html');
});
app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Ridehub server running!');
})
```